# Use bind-attr helper with input helper in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I want to use bind-attr and input helpers together so i can assign class to my input field. I have a workaround to do so like creating a parent dom and use bind-attr on that

```
<td {{bind-attr class="showmsg:alert-msg"}} >{{input type="text" value=rank}}</td>
```

How can I use bind-attr inside the input helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Views: Customizing a View's Element](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/) for general view customisation.

---

You can use `classNameBindings` in much of the same sort as you are using in `bind-attr` above.

**In view:**

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['showmsg:alert-msg'],
  showmsg: true
});
```

---

If you want to do something such as dynamic classes, you can pass values to your `view` through, for example, a `controller`:

**In template:**

`{{view 'some-td-view' classBinding="typeClass"}}`

where `typeClass` refers to a property on the `controller`

**In Controller:**

```
typeClass: function() {
    return this.get('type');
}.property('type')
```

**In View (views/some-td-view.js):**

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  tagName: 'td',
  classNames: ['some-default-class'],
});
```

So dependant on the `controller`'s value of `type` you can have a variable `typeClass`. For a `type` of `multi` would result in a view of:

`<td class="some-default-class multi"></td>`

whereas a `type` of single would result in:

`<td class="some-default-class single"></td>`